# Can a maxima condition be proved for the combination formula?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So a question in my math book requires me to somewhat show that for this particular problem nCr=n!/((n-r)!(r)!) is maximum at r=n/2 and the given solution is to put all the given values of r in the formula...I was wondering if there was any way to prove this generally if it even is true and not a coincidence for this particular problem.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Please edit your question with any attempts or thoughts you have at answering your question. This helps people understand exactly what you need help with and shows that you are putting in an effort. Please edit your post using [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make it easier to read.

Comment: What is "particular" about the problem?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Its just an easy probability problem that I solved with this formula but it led me to think if it is possible to prove the above.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is straightforward.  First note that $\binom{n}{n}=\binom{n}{n-r}$.  Then for $r+1\le \frac{n}{2}$, $\binom{n}{r}\lt \binom{n}{r+1}$.  If $n$ is even, then $\binom{n}{n/2}$ is the max.  If $n$ is odd then $\binom {n}{(n-1)/2}=\binom{n}{(n+1)/2}$ is max.

Comment: Thanks man but please explain like I'm five.

Comment: It will be much appreciated.

Comment: Which steps do you want explained?  Each step is simply arithmetic.  First, $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$  For $r+1\le \frac{n}{2}$, $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}\times\frac{n-r}{r+1}=\frac{n!}{(r+1)!(n-r-1)!}$ and $\frac{n-r}{r+1}\gt 1$.